# How to execute the method at desired time everyday

Tags: java, time, timer, calendar, scheduler

I have a method which should be executed everyday indefinitely. If the time is missed (because of the machine/laptop being inactive) then it should be executed next day. This should be running all the time.

Comment: Depending on your operating system it might be worth it exploring its scheduling facilities instead of doing it via code.

Comment: I agree with @FedericoklezCulloca. You have described a cron job. Get rid of the scheduling part of your code, and just focus on the `//method to be called`. Then, write a script or something that will execute your Java file, and then put that script on the crontab. Cron jobs are easy to make and maintain, and even though scheduling them is a bit tricky, there are a million resources on how to do so online.

Comment: Using cron (or at) is the way to go if you aren't writing Java server code. If you are writing Java server code, [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) *might* be worth investigating.

Comment: If you want to do it in Java, don’t use `Calendar` and `Timer`, they are outdated and `Calendar` in particular is poorly designed and cumbersome to work with. Use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). And use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please search before asking. Similar requirements are treated on a wealth of websites.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Spring along with Java one option is to use @Scheduled along with a cron expression.

Something like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 21 * * ?", zone = "Europe/Paris")
```

You can find more about @Scheduled here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks.

And you can play with cron expressions here: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html